# Global template for Django

Tags: django, templates

I am creating a webpage that contains several area that always look the same. Just wonder does Django support "global" template?

If it does, is there any reference that I can follow. (I try to google "Django global template" but not such similar things comes up).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django's [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance) exactly solves this problem. You can create one base template and change just a block that needs to change in the derived sub-pages.